# Advantage/Disadvantage between Chainlink VRF and an off-chain random number transaction performed by your server?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

As I understand it Chainlink VRF uses the request-response approach for providing contracts with a "trusted random number". You (the developer) create a smart contract and inherit the Chainlink VRFConsumerBase contract, declare a storage variable that will hold your random number result, then initialize some keyhash & chainlink oracle address, and implement a function ( lets say abc() ) that calls Chainlinks "requestRandomness()" function. You then override the internal "fulfillRandomness()" function and set the returned random number on your storage variable.

Short flow:

1. Fund your smart contract with LINK, make a transaction call to abc()
2. Wait for Chainlinks Oracle to make a transaction call to your contract "fulfillRandomness()" and set the random number result on your storage variable.

Rather than using this approach wouldn’t it be sufficient to just write a smart contract that emits a "RequestRandom" Event and have a personal server running that listens for the RequestRandom event of your contract and have that server then generate a random number and make an authorized transaction to my contract to set that generated random number on it.

```
contract MyRandom {

    event RequestRandom(uint seed);

    address public myServerWallet;
    uint public myRandomNumber;

    constructor(address a) {
       myServerWallet = a;
    }

    function makeRandomRequest(uint seed) external {
        emit RequestRandom(seed);
    }

    function setRandomResult(uint result) external {
        require(msg.sender == myServerWallet, "Only server may call");
        myRandomNumber = result;
    }
}
```

What would be the difference between this approach vs Chainlink VRF? Am I sacrificing some type of security by using this approach?

Tried the server approach above. It does work but still curious on advantage/disadvantage.

Comment: Think from the user's perspective. - How can I be sure your server will return indeed the random number, not the predefined one? - How can I be sure, your server will be running, listening for events, and then emitting the random numbers?

Comment: @tenbits fully understandable concern, with dapps there is a level of trust to be created between your dapp and your user. In video games we trust the devs to use rng fairly. Additionally we can ask the same question for chainlink VRF and what makes it so that cheaper solutions cannot be considered?

Comment: Absolutely, if your users trust your Random Number Provider and it is uptime, for sure you can use a more efficient solution. In your sample is not clear how the contract, which calls the `makeRandomRequest` will receive that number and proceed with the execution?